# how to find number of days in PHP when from date and to date is same

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, orocrm

i am trying to calculate between two dates using `\DateTime::createFromFormat`  .

but i am not able to find the difference between two same dates . like for one day it should show one days.
below is my code.

```php
    $fromDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y', $request->get('fromDateVal')); 
    $toDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y', $request->get('toDateVal')); 
    $diffdays = $toDate->diff($fromDate) ;
```

any help will be helpful.

i am getting this

```
    DateInterval {#7658
  interval: 0s
  +"y": 0
  +"m": 0
  +"d": 0
  +"h": 0
  +"i": 0
  +"s": 0
  +"f": 0.0
  +"weekday": 0
  +"weekday_behavior": 0
  +"first_last_day_of": 0
  +"invert": 0
  +"days": 0
  +"special_type": 0
  +"special_amount": 0
  +"have_weekday_relative": 0
  +"have_special_relative": 0
}
```

Comment: _"i am not able to find the difference between two same date"_ - Could it be because there is no difference to find if the dates are the same?

Comment: i know difference will give 0, i want to add 1 when it is zero. but this is giving dateinterval object. when i do +1 it will return false

Comment: You might want to look [in the manual for diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to understand what that method actually returns and how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use DateTime::diff() function

The DateTime::diff() function is an inbuilt function in PHP which is used to return the difference between two given DateTime objects.

```
<?php

// Initialising the two datetime objects 

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2019-9-10'); 
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2019-9-15'); 

// Calling the diff() function on above 
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2); 

// Getting the difference between two 
echo $difference->format('%R%a days'); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
if($fromDate == $toDate){
    $diffdays = 0;
}
```

I don't know if this is what you want. But basically add a condition to see if they are the same, and add the value you want. I added 0 since I think that's what the difference should be.

Comment: if ```$fromdate == $todate``` then i want to add 1 ,like i want to return the days count 1,

Comment: @AshishVC is this what you wanted, to do something when values are equal?

Comment: @AshishVC if($fromDate == $toDate){
    $diffdays = 1;
}